# How to join information from 3 tables into 1 column?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables dogs, breeds and entries. I need to get AVG(score) from entries, Name from dogs and name from breeds.

I have managed to connect 2 tables together and I'm struggle to get the last thing (`breeds.name`) attached to the table

```
SELECT AVG(score), dogs.name, dogs.breed_id
FROM entries  
JOIN dogs
    ON entries.dog_id = dogs.id
JOIN breeds
    ON breeds.id = dogs.breed_id
GROUP BY breeds.name, dogs.name, dogs.breed_id 
having count(entries.dog_id) > 1 
order by AVG(score) DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

current result:

[image]

How do I change     `breed_id`     for `breed.name` instead?

Comment: SELECT AVG(score), dogs.name, dogs.breed_id, breeds.name ?  You also need to change the GROUP BY order.

Comment: Welcome! Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See also: ["how to format a table in a post"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277716/11107541).

Comment: What happens if you just replace `dogs.breed_id` with `breeds.name` in the `SELECT` list?

Comment: Instead of `SELECT AVG(score), dogs.name, dogs.breed_id`, try with `SELECT *, AVG(score)` and see all the columns first. Then you'll know what the available columns are and can construct your `SELECT` section accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you need name from breeds, name from dogs, and AVG(score) from entries, the following SQL should do that.

```
SELECT breeds.name, dogs.name, AVG(score)
FROM entries  
JOIN dogs ON entries.dog_id = dogs.id
JOIN breeds ON breeds.id = dogs.breed_id
GROUP BY breeds.name, dogs.name
order by AVG(score) DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You have answered your own question within the question. All you need to do is replace `dogs.breed_id` with `breeds.name`. As this will leave you with two columns named `name` in your result set you should alias them to make it clearer.

Assuming that the id columns are defined as PRIMARY KEYs you can GROUP BY dogs.id (or entries.dog_id) as both of the non-aggregated columns (dogs.name and breeds.name) are functionally dependent on dogs.id.

```
SELECT AVG(e.score) avg_score, d.name dog_name, b.name breed_name
FROM entries e
JOIN dogs d ON e.dog_id = d.id
JOIN breeds b ON b.id = d.breed_id
GROUP BY d.id
HAVING COUNT(e.dog_id) > 1
ORDER BY avg_score DESC 
LIMIT 10
```